# Getty and inittab missing from Raspbian

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raspbian, tty, autologin

I have this command from an Old Rasbian Script

```
sed -i '/6:23:respawn:\/sbin\/getty 38400 tty6/a 8:23:respawn:\/sbin\/getty --autologin mon --noclear 38400 tty8' /etc/inittab
```

Unfortuantely the new version of Rasbian I am using Jessie does not have an inittab anymore - Does anyone know what file I should be updating.

Basically I need my linux device to auto-logon with the user 'mon' and no password.

Can anyone advise

Answer (score 0):

`apt-get install sysvinit sysvinit-core`

Comment: How about explaining what is accomplished by installing each of those packages?